# encoding error while testing email body with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test an email sending with confirmation code, but I have issue with body encoding

confirm_spec.rb:

```
describe Confirm do
  describe "email" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, password_reset_token: "token") }
    let(:mail) { Confirm.send_code(user) }

    it "has right recipient" do
      mail.to.should eq([user.email])
    end

    it "has right confirmation link" do
      mail.body.encoded.should match(confirm_url(user.confirmation_code))
    end
  end
end
```

send_code.html.erb:

```
your activation link  <%= confirm_url(@user.confirmation_code)%>
```

ERROR: test is failing with error

```
1) Confirm email has right confirmation link
 Failure/Error: mail.body.encoded.should match(confirm_url(user.confirmation_code))
   expected "\r\n----==_mimepart_53882564b695d_9acb3ff34d05e454141a4\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n\r\n----==_mimepart_53882564b695d_9acb3ff34d05e454141a4\r\nContent-Type: text/html;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n0LLQsNGI0LAg0YHRgdGL0LvQutCwINC00LvRjyDQsNC60YLQuNCy0LDRhtC4\r\n0LggaHR0cDovL2RyYXN0ZS5kZXYvY29uZmlybXMvdFBwRkR2S20K\r\n\r\n----==_mimepart_53882564b695d_9acb3ff34d05e454141a4--\r\n" to match "http://draste.dev/confirms/tPpFDvKm"
 # ./spec/mailers/confirm_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

software:

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
rails '3.2.15'
rspec-rails '2.11.0'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Looks like your content is encoded ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"). Did you try encoding your link before attempting to match? You are testing against the encoded body ("mail.body.encoded"), what about testing against just mail.body?

Comment: when testing just mail.body have an error: Confirm has right confirmation link
     Failure/Error: mail.body.should match(confirm_url(user.confirmation_code))
       expected #<Mail::Body:0x007fc370902eb0 @boundary="--==_mimepart_5388aa6540311_9c483fe1b505e4582995", ...

Comment: tried to encode links to base64 and still have an error expected "\r\n----==_mimepart_5388aba9e88a1_9c643fe84585e45062958\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n\r\n- ...